# Should i use a declaration or this() when passing the handle to a child class in java?

Tags: java, this, declaration

If i have a class that creates a new object and passes a refrence to this() to that new object, should i just use this() or should i create a declaration to that class and pass the declaration instead. I cant seem to find a clear example of when i would use each case when passing a handle to a child object.

```
public class ThisClass {

    ThisClass decHandle;
    ThisClass someThing = this;
    public String decString = "some string";
    SomeOtherClass classObject1 = new SomeOtherClass(this);
    SomeOtherClass classObject2 = new SomeOtherClass(decHandle);
    SomeOtherClass classObject3 = new SomeOtherClass(someThing);

}

public class SomeOtherClass {

    ThisClass decHandle;
    public SomeOtherClass (ThisClass handle){
        decHandle = handle; 
    }
    String valueForOther = decHandle.someThing;

}
```

I mostly need to know which is the best practice when passing handles to a child class from the parent.

Comment: This question was before i better understood java, i was designing a singleton and trying to figure out how to access it from other classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few mistakes here.

1) The last statement in SomeOtherClass should be

```
String valueForOther = decHandle.decString;
```

instead of

```
String valueForOther = decHandle.someThing;
```

2) When you say

```
SomeOtherClass classObject1 = new SomeOtherClass(this);
```

it will throw a NullPointerException, because you have not yet constructed the object. "this" refers to the current object. In your code, there is no object, therefore this line will throw an exception. The same applies to the next line.

3) "Child" means that the class inherits from a parent. Just because SomeOtherClass has a reference to ThisClass, it doesn't mean that SomeOtherClass is a child.

4) It's not a good practice to let a class' members have public visibility.

Ok, so here's how you would do it.

```
public class ThisClass 
{
    private String decString = "some string";
    private SomeOtherClass someOtherClass;

    public ThisClass()
    {
        someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass(this);
    }

    public String getDecString()
    {
        return decString;   
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass 
{

    private ThisClass decHandle;
    private String valueForOther;

    public SomeOtherClass (ThisClass handle)
    {
        decHandle = handle;
        valueForOther = decHandle.getDecString(); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you CodeBlue thats exactly the information i needed to know on accessing information between a class and the class that created it. 

I'm still working on learning to shift my mindset to object oriented and also java

Comment: Just an update, This was exactly the information i needed at the time to start playing with java code while reading as much as possible. Coming from a background that mainly was php, perl and js I didn't have a good foundation to learn java and OOP at the same time.

I was also having problems grasping how to call one object from another once I created it and released it off into ram.

This is mainly because i learn by coding by looking at existing code and taking it apart.



Thanks again CodeBlue and El developer for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
SomeOtherClass classObject1 = new SomeOtherClass(this);
```

Creating an instance variable that points to `this` doesn't achieve anything: You're just duplicating what `this` does anyway.

EDIT: Remember that variables (other than primitives) are all references in Java, so `this` and `someThing` in your example both point to the same object. It then doesn't matter which one you pass to `SomeOtherClass`; it will receive a reference to the same object either way.

The `handle` local variable in `SomeOtherClass` doesn't know or care where its reference came from.

Note that in your example `ThisClass.decHandle` is null because you have not assigned a value to it. (In fact `ThisClass` probably won't compile because of the uninitialized value, but I haven't tested that)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use `this` when you need to pass a reference to "this" object.  That's what it is there for (among other things).  If you try to avoid using it you end up making your code more verbose and less readable and / or using more memory at runtime.

(The use of `this` for *other* purposes (e.g. to distinguish fields and locals) is debatable, but it is hard to make a convincing case that it is "best practice" ... or not.  Anyway, that's a different question.)